# Javascript RegExp match text between <a> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to match with a javascript RegExp the string: bimbo999 from this a tag:     `<a href="/game.php?village=828&amp;screen=info_player&amp;id=29956" >bimbo999</a>`

The numbers from URL vars (village and id) are changing every time so I have to match the numbers somehow with RegExp.

```
</tr>
                    <tr><td>Sent</td><td >Oct 22, 2011  17:00:31</td></tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" height="160" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 4px;">
                            <table width="100%">
    <tr><th width="60">Supported player:</th><th>
    <a href="/game.php?village=828&amp;screen=info_player&amp;id=29956" >bimbo999</a></th></tr>
    <tr><td>Village:</td><td><a href="/game.php?village=828&amp;screen=info_village&amp;id=848" >bimbo999s village (515|520) K55</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Origin of the troops:</td><td><a href="/game.php?village=828&amp;screen=info_village&amp;id=828" >KaLa I (514|520) K55</a></td></tr>
    </table><br />

    <h4>Units:</h4>
    <table class="vis">
```

I tried with this:

```
var match = h.match(/Supported player:</th>(.*)<\/a><\/th></i);
```

but is not working. Can you guys, help me?

Comment: Why are you manipulating the HTML directly?  It's much safer (and usually easier) to work through the DOM.  Find the right `<table>`, then the appropriate `<a>` tags in the table using jQuery or a cross-browser selector library like Sizzle and then just get the innerHTML of the `<a>` tag to get bimbo999.

Comment: Using regex to traverse html tags is not very good practice. Have you tried making a DOM element from the tag and getting innerHTML?

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
/<a[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/a>/
```

- `<a[^>]*>` matches the opening `a` tag
- `([\s\S]*?)` matches any characters before the closing tag, as few as possible
- `<\/a>` matches the closing tag

The `([\s\S]*?)` captures the text between the tags as argument 1 in the array returned from an `exec` or `match` call.

This is really only good for *finding* text within `a` elements, it's not incredibly safe or reliable, but if you've got a big page of links and you just need their text, this will do it.

---

A much safer way to do this without RegExp would be:

```
function getAnchorTexts(htmlStr) {
    var div,
        anchors,
        i,
        texts;
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    anchors = div.getElementsByTagName('a');
    texts = [];
    for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; i += 1) {
        texts.push(anchors[i].text);
    }
    return texts;
}
```

Comment: `/<a[^>]*>((?:.|\r?\n)*?)<\/a>/` is also handy for matching to the next closing tag over multiple lines.

Comment: It would match over multiple lines already `\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have experience with Regex, but I think you can use JQuery with `.text()` !

[JQuery API - .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

I mean if you use :

```
var hrefText = $("a").text();
```

You will get your text without using Regex!

`.find("a")` and then gives you a list of **a**'s tags objects and then use `.each()` to loop on that list then you can get the text by using `.text()`.

Or your can use a class selector, id or anything you want!

Comment: this could also be done with regular javascript using `getElementsByTagName('a')`. Not a bad idea.

Comment: As a side note, it's not a good idea to use regex to parse HTML :)