# parse text using regex using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
txt = '<a class="info" href="/some/link" original-title="hello world <br/> Monday <br/> 2 days <br/> Test"> 10 </a>';

var pattern = /\s\d+/;
var parsed_data = parseInt((txt.match(pattern)||['0'])[0]);
```

Got this regex pattern from some example. I am trying to parse the text i.e. value 10 from the anchor tag. But the value obtained is 2.

EDIT:
I am using datatables to populate the tables.
And problem is the string i.e. txt is a row element, extracted from table using loop and need to add these values e.g.

```
var parsed_data += parseInt((txt.match(pattern)||['0'])[0]);
```

Comment: The pattern you are using is wrong since it gets the first number preceded by a space. In this case, it is 2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do but why not just use jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to parse a html content with regex, in this case use jQuery to fix it

```
var txt = '<a class="info" href="/some/link" original-title="hello world <br/> Monday <br/> 2 days <br/> Test"> 10 </a>';

var parsed_data = parseInt($(txt).text(), 10);
console.log(parsed_data)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kp5M3/)

Comment: Your parseInt should have 10 as a second parameter to treat the data as base 10. If your data is like "045", it will be parsed as base 8 (octal) since it starts with 0.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864723/javascript-regexp-match-text-between-a-tags

Comment: Or without jQuery: `var d = document.createElement('div'); d.innerHTML = txt; var parsed = parseInt(d.textContent, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like that:

```
var txt = '<a class="info" href="/some/link" original-title="hello world <br/> Monday <br/> 2 days <br/> Test"> 10 </a>';

var pattern = /.*>\s*(\d+)/;
var matches = txt.match(pattern);
var parsed = matches ? +matches[1] : 0;
```

However, this regexp takes just the last digit inside a tag (>): if you want to have something more precise, you should parse the HTML using the DOM – that is more expensive. It's really depends by what is your data, if you always have such format, you don't need the DOM.